# Why does this output the first element in the tuple?

Tags: python

I was reading through some answers and this was a solution to printing **['Bill', 'John', 'Tony', 'Phill']** from the list below.

```
mylist = [('Bill', 1), ('John', 1), ('Tony', 2), ('Phill', 2)]
print([x for x, y in mylist])
```

What does this line do?

```
print([x for x, y in mylist])
```

Comment: Try `tup = ("foo", 1); x, y = tup; print(x); print(y)` and see what happens.

Comment: Also once you do that, try just writing `[i for i in mylist]` and see what that returns

Comment: A simpler way would be just write `x,y = ('Bill',1)`. Now print x and y individually.

Comment: ok thanks, I completely understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
x,y in mylist[i]
```

saves the name of a certain tuple in x and the number in y.

```
for x,y in mylist
```

cycles through all the tuples in mylist.

```
print([x for x,y in mylist])
```

prints the x of every tuple.

```
print([y for x,y in mylist])
```

would print all the numbers.

```
print([z for z in mylist])
```

would print all the tuples.